# how to compare an integer from an arraylist

Tags: java, comparison, equals

I have this piece of code:

```
    public static ArrayList type = new ArrayList<Integer>();

///////////some code//////////

    System.out.println(normalization.type.get(i));
    System.out.println(normalization.type.get(i) == "1");
```

it gives me output

```
1
false
```

I have tried single quotes and equals methods, still doesn't match.
Any ideas ??

Comment: Use `equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: Of course not with `"1"`.

Comment: And remove the doublequotes.  it's an Integer value, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Integer is an Object, so you have to use the `equals` method.

Moreover, `"1"` is a String so it can't be equals to the Integer 1
You must do the following:

```
System.out.println(normalization.type.get(i).equals(new Integer(1)));
```

OR

```
System.out.println(normalization.type.get(i).equals(1));
```

Comment: There's pretty much no reason to use `new Integer()`. If anything, use the static `Integer#valueOf()` factory method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that latter translates to the former.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `Integer` to `String`

```
normalization.type.get(i) == "1"
```

`"1"` is a String and type has Integers in it.

Use:

```
  normalization.type.get(i).equals(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose as an alternative, you could always try using the `Objects#equals(Object, Object)` which came out in Java 7. The following code will print `true` if the element at index `i` is equal to `1`:

`System.out.println(Objects.equals(normalization.type.get(i), 1));`

Here is the implementation for that method:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Your problem is that you're trying to compare an `Integer` with a `String` which will always return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an Integer with a String. (or char, when you use single quotes)

Try normalization.type.get(i) == 1